# Cast a dynamic attribute after it's posted (Model binding)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What I have is a model which has one of it's attributes dynamic. This dynamic attribute holds one of about 50 different objects. This model is send to a view that dynamic creates the page based on which object is used. This is working perfectly ... the issue is the postback. When the model posts back the modelbinder is not able to bind the dynamic attribute. I was expecting this and thought I would be able to handle it but nothing that I tried works appart from making an action for EACH different objects.

Model

```
public class VM_List
{
    public Config.CIType CIType { get; set; }
    public dynamic SearchData { get; set; }
   //Lots of static fields
}
```

This works

```
public ActionResult List_Person(VM_List Model, VM_Person_List SearchData)
{
Model.SearchData = SearchData;
//Stuff
}

public ActionResult List_Car(VM_List Model, VM_Car_List SearchData)
{
Model.SearchData = SearchData;
//Stuff
}
```

But what I want is a single action

```
public ActionResult List(VM_List Model)
{
    //Stuff
}
```

I have tried things like

```
public ActionResult List(VM_List Model)
{

        switch (Model.CIType)
        {
            case Config.CIType.Person:
                UpdateModel((VM_Person_List)Model.SearchData);
                break;
            default:
                SearchData = null;
                break;
        }

    //Stuff
}
```

and a Custom modelbinder

```
CIType CIType = (CIType)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("CIType").ConvertTo(typeof(CIType));

switch (CIType)
{
            case Config.CIType.Person:
                SearchData = (VM_Person_List)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("SearchData").ConvertTo(typeof(VM_Person_List));
                break;
            default:
                SearchData = null;
                break;
        }
```

but I can't get either to work. Any ideas?

Comment: When you use CIType how did you define it in your third or fourth example shouldn't you define it as part of the model like you do in example 1 or 2 ??

Comment: I missed out the "Model." when I was simplifying the code. Added it in.

Comment: can you make the SearchData field generic instead of dynamic?  or maybe use an interface?  having to account for 50 concrete class implementations is a serious code-smell

Comment: They can't be generic. Generic Attributes are in VM_List. The "SearchData" is the non generic fields. For Car it would be Make, Model, CC, Year and a Person FirstName, LastName, birthday, email etc. 50 ViewModels is fine, there is no getting around it ... Using the dynamic field I have no need for 50 views (I have that part working fine) and 50 Actions (this is the part thats not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many different things I finally found a way that works.

Action:

```
public ActionResult List(VM_List Model)
{

//If the defaultmodelbinder fails SearchData will be an object
if(Model.SearchData.GetType() == typeof(object))
{

//Get SearchData as a Dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> DSearchData = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("SearchData.")).ToDictionary(k => k.Substring(11), k => Request.QueryString[k]);

switch (Model.CIType)
{
                case Config.CIType.Person:
                    Model.SearchData = new VM_Person_List(DSearchData);
                    break;
                case Config.CIType.Car:
                    Model.SearchData = new VM_Car_List(DSearchData);
                    break;
}

//Rest of action
//..
        }
```

and for each object make a constructor that accepts a dictionary

```
public VM_Car_List(Dictionary<string, string> DSearchData)
{
    this.Make = Convert.ToInt32(DSearchData["Make"]);
    this.Model = Convert.ToInt32(DSearchData["Model"]);
    this.Year = Convert.ToInt32(DSearchData["Year"]);
    // ETC
}
```